# Couldn't get correct Output

Tags: java, string, while-loop

**You give your guess and programm compare the result** with random word from the list. If the the programm could find equal symbouls, there will be shown, if not you will see "#"-symbol. Now, I can't understand why "#" didn't dysplayed. Here is a full code.

> Example:

- apple – random word
- apricot - answer of customer
- ap############# (15 syllables, because of customer don't have to know
  the lenght of word)

  import java.util.Random;
      import java.util.Scanner;

  ```
  public class Main {
      private static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

      public static final int N = 30;

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          String ranWord;
          Random rand = new Random();

          String[] words = new String[N];
          words[0] = "appricot";
          words[1] = "orange";
          words[2] = "cucumber";
          words[3] = "potato";
          words[4] = "tomato";
          words[5] = "cherry";
          words[6] = "banana";
          words[7] = "carrot";
          words[8] = "were";
          words[10] = "very";
          words[11] = "tasty";
          words[12] = "as";
          words[13] = "usual";
          words[14] = "and";
          words[15] = "fresh";
          words[16] = "and";
          words[17] = "tasty";
          words[18] = "passed";
          words[19] = "for";
          words[20] = "cooking";
          words[21] = "a";
          words[22] = "chicken";
          words[23] = "it";
          words[24] = "isn't";
          words[25] = "necessary";
          words[26] = "cook";
          words[27] = "chicken";
          words[28] = "every";
          words[29] = "day";

          System.out.println("Try to guess the word, call Your variant?" + "\n");
          ranWord = words[rand.nextInt(N)];
          System.out.println("Computer guess the word: " + ranWord);

          Computer computer = new Computer(ranWord);

          String customWord = scan.nextLine();
          Customer customer = new Customer(customWord);

          boolean finish = true;
          while (!finish) {
              //customWord = scan.nextLine();
              if (customer.word.equals(computer.ranWord)) {
                  System.out.println("Succsesful prompt!");
                  finish = true;
              } else {
                  checkIsFinish(customWord, ranWord);
                  finish = false;
              }
          }
      }

      static void checkIsFinish(String customWord, String ranWord) {
          int minLenghtWord = customWord.length() < ranWord.length() ? customWord.length() : ranWord.length();

          for (int i = 0; i < minLenghtWord; i++) {
              if (customWord.charAt(i) == ranWord.charAt(i)) {
                  System.out.print(ranWord.charAt(i));
              } else {
                  System.out.print("#");
              }
          }
          for (int i = 0; i < 15 - minLenghtWord; i++) {
              System.out.print("#");
          }
          System.out.println(customWord.length());
       }
      }
  ```

Comment: you don't print them in 1 line, you split it into 15 lines with `System.out.println` for 1 line without breaks use `System.out.print`

Comment: It doesn't matter. I used "print". I cannot see the result of method checkIsFinish. I don't understand, if the program use it

Comment: the problem seems to be somewhere else. you method `checkisFinish` works fine. i tried with `checkIsFinish("apricot","apple");` and got output: `ap#############
7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a silly mistake you made. You never enter `while` because `finish = true` at the start.

Do this,

```
finish = true;
while (finish) {
    //customWord = scan.nextLine();
    if (customer.word.equals(computer.ranWord)) {
        System.out.println("Succsesful prompt!");

    } else {
        checkIsFinish(customWord, ranWord);
    }
    finish = false;

}
```

Or,

```
finish = false;
while (!finish) {
    //customWord = scan.nextLine();
    if (customWord.equals(ranWord)) {
        System.out.println("Succsesful prompt!");

    } else {
        checkIsFinish(customWord, ranWord);
    }
    finish = true;

}
```